# How do I write a synopsis for a scientific article? publication?

Tags: formatting, scientific-publishing, synopsis

I want to submit an article under the "Analysis" of a journal. Their website says that authors are required to submit a synopsis first.

I know that synopsis is like a summary of article, but how exactly should be its format? I don't know. Can you please tell? What things should I include in it? In which order they should be? Am I required to tell just about the article or about me and my background too? Anything else that needs to be included? How long it should be?

Comment: Do you have an advisor?

Answer (score 1):

A synopsis is (effectively) a compressed version of the introduction and conclusion of your article. You don't need to include lit review, methodology, data, or analysis; just tell them what you were trying to do and what you found. If it helps, think of it as a long abstract. They will ask you for more information if they want it.

All an editor wants in a synopsis is a sense of what you're doing, so they can see if it's a good fit for their publication. Don't be overly concerned about the details of formatting, because your synopsis will never see the light of day. Just be as clear and concise as you can, emphasizing anything novel or innovative about your research that might pique an editor's interest. A synopsis is a sales pitch: a moment for you to say: "Hey! This is what I'm doing; isn't it cool?!?" And yeah, I know... Everybody hates doing sales pitches, but (sadly) it's part of the game.

Comment: Thanks! And how long it should be?

Comment: I doubt that there's some set length, though it will obviously be longer than an abstract.  Imagine that you are explaining your research to a new grad student or an academic in a different field. Avoid unnecessary jargon and the minutia of in-discipline debates; tell them what you did and why it's interesting and important; don't bore them with intricate details or extended discussions. Say everything that needs to be said, but avoid things you just *want* to say. Follow the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), which is a good idea in most cases anyway.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.